# How to wrap child widgets in AppBar for larger child heights and paddings in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-appbar, flutter-design

I have struggled to find a method to fit the height of the AppBar based on action icon sizes and their padding. When padding is provided to leading and action icons, they are covered from the AppBar. Is there any kind of a method to achieve this feature?[This is how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRp14.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the app bar height based on the device height

```
 appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2), // here the desired height
          child: AppBar(
            // ...
          )
        ),
```